# How to run html form using facebook like button insted of normal button

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I need to run a html form after user click the facebook Like button.

```
<form method="get" action="$authaction">
     <input name="tok" value="$tok" type="hidden" />
     <input name="redir" value="$redir" type="hidden" />
     <iframe name="f7584763" width="450px" height="56px" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" title="fb:like Facebook Social Plugin" src="https://www.facebook.com/v2.0/plugins/like.php?action=like&amp;app_id=&amp;channel=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2FZEbdHPQfV3x.js%3Fversion%3D41%23cb%3Df7fe07bd8%26domain%3Dww1.cloudtrax.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fww1.cloudtrax.com%252Ff1e2fbf418%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FNero-Cafe-Bar%2F246550148703080&amp;layout=standard&amp;locale=el_GR&amp;sdk=joey" class="" style="font-size: 14px; border-style: none; visibility: visible; width: 450px; height: 56px;transform: scale(1.5);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
 -o-transform: scale(1.5);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
 transform-origin: top left;
 -ms-transform-origin: top left;
 -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
 -moz-transform-origin: top left;
 -webkit-transform-origin: top left;"></iframe>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery.

```
$(function () {
    $('.facebookbutton').on('click', function (e) {
        $('.formbuttonclass').click();
    });
});
```

The form button can be hidden.
You can use ID's as well. pleace #id between ''.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.1

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (url, html_element) {
    //will get called whenever a user likes or unlikes a like button
    console.log(url);
});
```